# Search Provider Sharepoint Refinement 2010

Tags: enterprise-search

I'm using the Search Provider KeywordQuery with Sharepoint 2010.
Would like to utilize the functionality of Refinement Results. However from what I have researched this only works with Fast Provider.

Following part of my code:

```
KeywordQuery keywordquery = new KeywordQuery(new SPSite(Site));
keywordquery.QueryText = "temp";
keywordquery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RefinementResults;
keywordquery.EnableFQL = true;
keywordquery.Refiners = "Tags";
keywordquery.HiddenConstraints = "scope:ScopeItems";
keywordquery.RowLimit = 500;
keywordquery.StartRow = 0;
keywordquery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.SharepointSearch;
ResultTableCollection collectionItems = keywordquery.Execute();

collectionItems.Count; // equal 0 zero
```

Just wanted to confirm that this works with Refinement provider of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

RefinementResults is valid for SP Search: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.resulttype(v=office.14).aspx

Do you want the refined results after someone used the refiner like its done in a search center?

Comment: Yes I want to make like a search center. What I do not understand, is where my code is wrong. If I change my ResultType RelevantResults he brings to the records normally.